# Setting layer order for output in QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis

I've recently discovered the graphical modeler in QGIS and I've managed to speed up my workflow significantly when doing ecological and geo/hydrological analyses on a landscape level. Al though I still haven't figured out how to get my output layers to stack as I want them to.

A typical model looks like this (some Swedish in there):[image]

I input a DEM and two kinds of landscape erosion maps (one vector and one raster) and the model cuts them from a nation wide extent down to the extent of the DEM and then styles them. The model also creates a hill-shade layer and contours.

The "problem" arise when the model completes and and all my newly created layers end up scrambled and I have to order them by hand (yes, I'm lazy) - is there a way to get them to come out in the order I want: hill-shade at the bottom with the erosion maps on top and finally the contours?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough if you use the Dependencies option at the end of every Algorithm within the Graphical modeler. By specifying which algorithms your current algorithm is dependent on, you can decide the order in which they will be processed. If you already established that Alg2 is dependent on Alg1, and you want Alg3 to be next, no need to specify that it is dependent on Alg1 and Alg2. Just specify the last element in the order (in this case Alg2), and the program will understand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like currently the order is totally random https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44184

Comment: Starting with QGIS 3.32, it is possible to reorder model output layers:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/52996